# Multiplying and adding values from csv file in python

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I have a csv file with following data, I want to know how to multiply values in Qty column with Avg cost column and then sum the values together.

```
| Instrument | Qty  | Avg cost  |
|------------|------|-----------|
| APLAPOLLO  | 1    | 878.2     |
| AVANTIFEED | 2    | 488.95    |
| BALAMINES  | 3    | 308.95    |
| BANCOINDIA | 5    | 195.2     |
| DCMSHRIRAM | 4    | 212.95    |
| GHCL       | 4    | 241.75    |
| GIPCL      | 9    | 102       |
| JAMNAAUTO  | 5    | 178.8     |
| JBCHEPHARM | 3    | 348.65    |
| KEI        | 8    | 121       |
| KPRMILL    | 2    | 592.65    |
| KRBL       | 3    | 274.45    |
| MPHASIS    | 2    | 519.75    |
| SHEMAROO   | 2    | 400       |
| VOLTAMP    | 1    | 924       |
```

Comment: Perhaps the best way to do this is using Pandas.  Give it a try and show us some code if you're stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saved the file as test.csv and did the following

```
import csv
with open('/tmp/test.csv', 'r') as f:
    next(f) #skip first row
    total = sum(int(row[1]) * float(row[2]) for row in csv.reader(f))
    print('The total is {}'.format(total))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
f=open('yourfile.csv','r')

temp_sum=0

for line in f:

 word=line.split(',')

 temp_sum=temp_sum+float(word[1])*float(word[2])

print(temp_sum)
```

Comment: This is a terrible way to [handle a csv file](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)

Comment: @ Wayne: I have worked on very large files (more than 200 MB in size) with this code. No issue found and it was simple & fast.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas
colnames = ['Qty', 'Avg_cost']
data = pandas.read_csv('test.csv', names=colnames) 
qty = data.Qty.tolist()
avg = data.Avg_cost.tolist()
mult = []
for i in range(0,len(qty)):
    temp = qty[i]*avg[i]
    mult.append(temp)
sum_all = sum(mul)
print sum_all
print mult
```